# Build a statement from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

Hi I have the biggest brain freeze, I'm trying to filter an array by key and value pairs stored in an object, problem I have is currently it just filters recursively like as if it was an AND operator between, but I'd like it to filter as if each statement was optional like an OR operator was between each filter.

This is the code I have currently

```
 Object.entries(filterCond).forEach(([key, value])=> {
          filtered = filtered.filter(function(){ 
              return jQuery(this).data(key).includes(+value)
          })
})
```

where filterCond contains the key value pair for the data attribute, if something is unclear feel free to ask Ill do my best to re-elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `filtered` so that each value has a callback called just once, and in the callback, check that `.some` of the `filterCond` are met.

Your `this` also incorrectly refers to the window inside your current callback - refer to the element being iterated over by using the callback's argument.

```
const elementsWithAtLeastOneMatch = filtered.filter(
  element => Object.entries(filterCond).some(
    ([key, value]) => $(element).data(key)?.includes(+value)
  )
);
```

Demo:

```js
const filterCond = {
  prop: '3',
  prop2: 'another',
};
const elements = [...$('.foo')];
const elementsWithAtLeastOneMatch = elements.filter(
  element => Object.entries(filterCond).some(
    ([key, value]) => $(element).data(key)?.includes(+value)
  )
);
console.log(elementsWithAtLeastOneMatch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" data-prop="'3'"></div>
<div class="foo" data-prop="'4'"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

But if the values you're looking for are in data attributes, there's no need to rely on a big library like jQuery for something so easy.

```
const elementsWithAtLeastOneMatch = filtered.filter(
  element => Object.entries(filterCond).some(
    ([key, value]) => element.dataset[key]?.includes(+value)
  )
);
```

Comment: thx I think your solution looks sound, but for some reason it is as if it cant read the element variable so it throws an undefined error
``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')``

Comment: If some of the data attributes might not exist, use optional chaining so an error doesn't get thrown when they're not found. (The same problem should have occurred in your original code too.)

Comment: nope it was just jquery which had overwritten how the regular filter function functions, but I've solved that part, now im just trying to make the filter part to function on my side